# How to clear system tray notification via command line

Tags: gnome, bash, notification-area

I have an application which produces system notification every 5 seconds.

Overtime the notification tray I have (Gnome env) gets crowded.

How can I clear it like every minute but I need to do this via bash so that I can automate it later.

### EDIT

I think I haven't made my question clear hence this edit.

I want to see the notifications. But as this is in GNOME env it gets accumulated in the notifications tray unless manually cleared.

I don't want to clear it manually... I want to clear it automatically after every 1 min. So I am looking for a way to do that from the command line so that I can later on code that into my application

Hope I have made my question clear...

Comment: which version of Gnome are you using? (I am also interested in a answer for 3.14)

Comment: I've got 3.10.4

Comment: You want to see notifications ?

Comment: @Raja Kindly see to the edit i made in the question

Comment: Would this only need to work in Gnome or for all environments?

Comment: Gnome is my current priority. . But a universal solution is welcomed

Comment: I think you can only do that in new notification system (Gnome 3.16) using dbus.

Comment: No way to do this in 3.10, sorry

Comment: What is creating the notifications? An app that you wrote, or some third-party app?

Answer (score 3):

If you wrote the application, you could just put a timeout on the notifications:

```
notify-send -t 5000 "Title" "Details"
```

If not, the only way I know of would be to restart the gnome desktop. You can do it by pushing Alt + F2, type "r" then Enter. But if you want to do it via command line:

```
killall -3 gnome-shell
```

Unfortunately the kill gnome option will interfere if you want to keep using applications during the flickery restart of gnome-shell.